# Errors when installing specific R packages

Tags: r, installation, package, osrm

I am receiving error messages when I try to install specific packages in R. The packages in question are `pillar` and `osrm`. I recently updated several packages without any problems so I'm not sure why these ones are causing an issue.

The error message I recieve when installing either of the two packages is as follows:

```
 There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
osrm  3.2.0  3.3.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘osrm’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/osrm_3.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 119746 bytes (116 KB)
downloaded 116 KB

'\\CompanyX\ProgData\R_Studio\R-34~1.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"X:/R_Studio/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "X:\R_Studio\R-3.4.1\library" C:\Users\abc123\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKk0RxD/downloaded_packages/osrm_3.3.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘osrm’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have seen in other posts that the binary/source issue is caused by recent updates to the package and this requires a compiler. As I am on a company machine, I am unable to easily install RTools. I have also installing tried older versions of each package - this results in the same error.

I have tried to download from Github directly via `devtools::install_github("rCarto/osrm")` but I always get the following error:

```
Installation failed: Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Timed out
```

I'm not sure if this is due to a company firewall blocking the access, but it seems to occur with any package I try to download from GitHub.

Finally, I have tried to install directly from the tar.gz file or a zip file downloaded from CRAN/GitHub. The former results in the following error:

```
'\\CompanyX\ProgData\R_Studio\R-34~1.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"X:/R_Studio/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "X:\R_Studio\R-3.4.1\library" "C:/Users/abc123/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKk0RxD/downloaded_packages/osrm_3.3.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/abc123/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKk0RxD/downloaded_packages/osrm_3.3.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

While the zip file route does place the package folder in the R root library folder but then results in a system error requesting the latest version of R and then crashes RStudio completely.

Any advice as to either successfully install these packages or a specific issue I could raise with the company IT department would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see the binary for 3.3.1 on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osrm/index.html Maybe try a different mirror or just be patient and wait a few hours.

Comment: You simply can't install source packages (`.tar.gz`) without Rtools on Windows.

Comment: @Roland I've tried swtiching mirrors and have repeated the install process over the last couple of days to try and avoid the binary delay and I'm still getting the same error message as in the question above. Do you need Rtools to install packages from a zip folder as well?

Comment: The zips are the binaries. The problem is probably your old R version. Upgrade R (binaries provided by CRAN are only for the current R version).

Comment: Or tell `install.packages` to install the old binary.

Comment: @Roland using `install.packages('C:/Users/abc123/AppData/Local/Temp/osrm_3.3.1.zip', repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")` I get the following error `Error in readRDS(pfile) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer` - I've had this before when trying to install from zip files - I'm guessing this requires the old binary. In the archive on CRAN the older versions are all tar.gz files - do you know where the old binary files in zip format can be obtained from?

Comment: Usually, `install.packages` would ask you if you want to install the newer version from source. You can say no. Also, upgrade R. You should not stay with such an old version (in particular, reasons for staying with an old version would also apply to packages, so they can't apply because you are trying to install new packages).

Comment: Solution - Installed the latest version of R and installed/loaded packages as normal